# Why does this Js code (using userAgents) not work on my iphone 4?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, user-agent

Sorry to ask such a vague question but I really can't pinpoint why this code works on my pc and on an android phone but not an iPhone 4 with safari or chrome? Checked all browser compatibility for `.includes` , `navigator.userAgent` and even `.getElementById`.. what am i missing?

html:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="go()">Click me</button>
```

js:

```
var devices = ["Android","iPhone","iPod","iPad","BlackBerry","Chrome"];
var UserAgents = navigator.userAgent;


function detectDevice() {
    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
      if (UserAgents.includes(devices[i])){
         return devices[i];
      }
    }
}


function go(){
var str = detectDevice();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `includes` has limited browser support, are you getting an error? Is that an issue? If you swap it to be `...indexOf(...) > -1` instead does it work? Did you debug to see what `UserAgents` returns?  `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = UserAgents;`

Comment: @epascarello I did debug and I couldn't see a problem, I had no way of checking errors on the iPhone 4. I checked includes and it supports the browser my phone was using? but didn't work, "index of" does seem to! thanks, you have been a big help!